# Intellij classpath add path and shorten

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, classpath

I am trying to add a path to a -classpath and shorten the command.

Adding a module works like this: `-cp $Classpath$;\another\module`
However now the command is to long to be executed.
Shortening command line does not for for argfile nor the jar.

[image]

Do you have any idea how to add a module and shorten the command only for the development purpose?

The general idea behind it is that I want to override one of my modules with custom used only for debugging and running on a development machine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.